# BLE connectivity not consistent on Samsung devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, galaxy, gatt

We are using Android BLE code for connection to a custom hardware and with most mobile devices, this works perfectly. However, when it comes to Samsung with the Android OS Version 6.0.1, attempt for connection is not successful in most cases.

The problem is happening after trying to connect to a device with `bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback);`
In `onConnectionStateChange` callback gatt status code 133 is received and in that case what the app does is to close the current instance of the `BluetoothGatt` and connect again to the device for a new `BluetoothGatt` instance. This workaround helps to get a connection after a couple of retries but this is definitely not the way how it should work.

After doing some BLE sniffing, it is clear that the device is not even trying to connect to the peripheral and just gives out the general gatt error (133). What is interesting that this has been a major problem only for the Marshmallow update, more specifically on the Android 6.0.1.

**So my question is whether anybody experienced similar connectivity issues with only selected devices, where the mobile device tries to connect to the device and instead receives 133 gatt status code?**

Comment: this is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465373/android-ble-gatt-error-133-getting-often-with-samsung-devices