# Android Ble GATT_ERROR 133 getting often with samsung devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, iot, gatt

I am working on BLE Applications, I have tested with different devices like Nexus, Moto, Samsung, LG. I am getting the GATT Error 133 in Samsung Devices alone(Samsung A5 2016). Trying to connect 10 times it gets connected only 2 or 3 times.Please Help me out.

Comment: Try to stop scanning during connection

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Am connecting after scanned devices. specifically above error occurs only Samsung devices

Comment: If you use direct connect (setting the autoConnect parameter to false), that error is returned when the attempt times out after about 30 seconds. Is that what you are getting?

Comment: Am getting status 133 in callback onConnectionStateChange